# cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

My data structure in cosmosdb is next

```
   {
      "_id": {
      "$oid": "554f7dc4e4b03c257a33f75c"
      },
      .................
   }
```

and I need to sort collection by `$oid` field. How should I form my sql query?

Normal query `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM collection c ORDER BY c._id.filedname` not works if `fieldname` starts with `$` like `$oid`.

I am using query explorer from azure portal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use a special character, like `$`, you need to use bracket notation:

```
SELECT c._id FROM c
order by c._id["$oid"]
```

You can do this with each property in the hierarchy, so the following also works:

```
SELECT c._id FROM c
order by c["_id"]["$oid"]
```

Comment: Sorry to necro this thread but I tried the notation you used in the ORDER BY clause but it doesn't seem to work on my end (ie: no results). Do you know where I went wrong here? The Fields.FieldId field is confirmed a numeric value and can confirm the specified Fields.FieldId value exists.

`SELECT c["Fields"]["FieldId"] FROM c WHERE c["Fields"]["FieldId"] = 32796`

Comment: @MiloUlver - I suggest posting a new question. That way, you can include sample data, along with a properly formatting query, along with the error(s) you get.