# Cosmos DB: Querying documents properties with special characters such as "$"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've got a Cosmos DB collection with a document that contains properties that have a special character and what I assume is a reserved word. An example document is:

```
{
   $type: 'Some value', 
   Value: 'Some other value'
}
```

If I execute the following query in the Azure Portal Query Explorer:

```
select * from c where c.Value = 'Some other value'
```

I receive an error of "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'Value'.". I get a similar error querying on c.$type.

How do I escape these property values so that I can query?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the case of special characters, you will need to wrap the property inside `[]`

Example:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["$type"] = "Some value"`

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["value"] = "$Some other value"`

Comment: What will happen if we want to save something like  value = "King"s" and then retrive it with select and where clause.