# How to deal with points in variables names in cosmos - documentDB?

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database

I made a mistake in a python script and some fields that should have been nested were created with a composite name (ex : "INFO.LEGAL")

I'm surprised that documentDB accepts such fields, I'm more surprised to find absolutely no way to query on those (in order to delete them).

syntaxes like `SELECT r.INFO.LEGAL FROM root r` or `SELECT * FROM root r WHERE IS_DEFINED(INFO.LEGAL) = true` are not working. And I can't find a trick equivalent to sqlserver's use of braces `[INFO.LEGAL]` to deal with anormal characters in fields names

Any ideas ?

Comment: Tried standard delimited identifiers? `SELECT r."INFO.LEGAL" FROM root r`.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, that's not a valid syntax

Comment: Take a look at my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219609/272109 - I believe your question is a duplicate, as it's solved the same way, with brackets (but in your example in your question, you used the brackets incorrectly). Also, your question comes off a bit strong, declaring there's "absolutely no way" to query with special characters.

Comment: fyi I tested your case with brackets. Works fine. So... marked this as a duplicate - just look at the answer to the other question, which shows proper bracket notation syntax. And that syntax works with `IS_DEFINED` as well.

Comment: Try something like `SELECT r["INFO.LEGAL"] FROM Root r`. I just tried it and I was able to get the documents.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. 


@DavidMakogon I didn't declared that there IS no way, i said i didn't find any. 
Thanks for providing the link, that's indeed a duplicate !

Comment: @GauravMantri correct. Which is why I marked as duplicate to my other answer, which describes that syntax  precisely. And works with `IS_DEFINED(r["LEGAL.INFO"])` equally well.