# Extracting data from array in Cosmos DB with format “$text”:”value”

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have data in Cosmos in the following format:

```
                        "Reference": [
                            {
                                "$text": "1024782114",
                                "@attr": {
                                    "Type": "ZCU",
                                    "Assignor": "Partner"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "$text": "1024782114",
                                "@attr": {
                                    "Type": "ShipmentId",
                                    "Assignor": "Consignor"
                                }
                            }]
```

And I can’t figure out how to query for the value of the $text fields as a query that contains a dollar sign obviously is wrong syntax.

Must be some projection magic I’m missing out on...

Comment: So I figured out myself. Syntax is field["$text"].

Comment: can you put your correct query in here?  field["$text"] doesn't work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name)