# How to query Cosmos DB with dashes in property name

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Question: What is the proper syntax for querying a COSMOS DB using the SQL API when dashes are used in the property name?

Error:
Failed to query item for container appointment: {"code":400,"body":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Gateway Failed to Retrieve Query Plan: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":7,"end":8},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near

This query works
SELECT a.ID
FROM accesspoint a

This query fails
SELECT a.Point-Name
FROM accesspoint a

What I've tried:
I tried wrapping the value in double quotes, single quotes, (), <>
Could not find any documentation on the use of dashes in the name

Comment: Did you try square brackets (`SELECT a.[Point-Name]...`).  That's Microsoft's default quoting mechanism for SQL Server. Probably for CosmosDB as well(?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name)

Answer (score 5):

[] and quotes

SELECT * FROM c where c["point-name"] = "Eastern Standard Time"

Thank you Bill