# Number as Json key in cosmos db (SQL)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a document with the following JSON.

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "user": {
        "456": true 
          } 
}
```

When I write SQL the key '456' is illegal.

```
SELECT * FROM c  where c.user.456 = true
```

Is there a way to user numbers as key in the query above? Also if I have a key with a period in it, the SQL search doesn't work.

Comment: Bracket notation is the way to get around this (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219609/272109)). Note: I do not recommend that schema. You have no easy way to search for keys (e.g. 456). You should consider changing your embedded user object to something like `"user": { "someId" : "456", "someValue": "true" } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c  where c.user['456'] = true
```

Hope this can help you:).

Comment: This approach works fine also in the case you want to find out whether a "number" key exists in an JSON object, i.e. IS_DEFINED(c.user['456']).