# Cosmos DB SQL API query problem - dot in property name

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In my Cosmos DB the nested property names include a .(dot). I've tried every combination I can think of including special character handling, but I keep getting the error "incorrect syntax". How can I handle the .(dot) to get the values in eRecord.01?

[image: data]

Comment: Solved this by using c.data.eRecord["eRecord.01"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name)

Comment: Yup the brackets are the way to go. FYI I've answered this for similar questions, such as the one I suggested as a duplicate (not *exact* duplicate, but fairly close, and with the same solution).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following syntax to solve your problem:

```
c.data.eRecord["eRecord.01"]
```