# Cosmos DB - How to access fields that have a space in their name?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have some data in Cosmos DB where the fields have spaces in their names, like this:

```
{
    "First Name": "John",
    "Middle Name": null,
    "Last Name": "Doe",
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to run some SQL queries from an Azure Notebook, but I can't access these fields in either of the following ways

```
select 
a.[First Name]
from SomeTable a
where a.id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

select 
a.["First Name"]
from SomeTable a
where a.id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

It works fine for fields that don't have a space. Is there a way to access these fields with spaces in the SELECT or WHERE clause?

Comment: Is this a Cosmos notebook or Synapse notebook?

Comment: @MarkBrown It's a Cosmos notebook, accessing directly from the Azure portal from the Data Explorer tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name)

Comment: Please see the linked question I shared, which is essentially the same thing (spaces are considered non-alphanumeric), and has an answer

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree it's similar/likely a duplicate. However I saw that other answer and missed that unlike in regular SQL, the bracket notation in the Cosmos SQL expects there to not be a period after the alias.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the way to do this is:

```
select 
a["First Name"]
from SomeTable a
where a.id = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

Don't add a period after the table/table alias...