# Cosmos DB - column alias with spaces

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I include spaces in column names in cosmos db?
When I run this in Cosmos DB Studio:

`SELECT c.Discriminator as "name with spaces" FROM c`

I get this error: `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Exceptions.ExpectedQueryPartitionProviderException: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":26,"end":44},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '\"name with spaces\"'."}]`

The syntax `["..."]` works when querying ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178809/cosmos-db-how-to-access-fields-that-have-a-space-in-their-name)), but not in the context from the example above.

Comment: If you're creating an alias, as in your example, remove those brackets and only use double-quotes (e.g. `as "name with spaces" from c`)

Comment: When running this: `SELECT c.Discriminator as "name with spaces" FROM c `
I get this error: `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Query.Core.Exceptions.ExpectedQueryPartitionProviderException: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":26,"end":44},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '\"name with spaces\"'."}]`

Comment: Please *edit your question* with such information - it's very hard to read formatted text in a comment. Also, please explain further *where* you're running this from: the portal? In code? (I run this in the portal with no issues)

Comment: I've updated my question with such information. Thank you.

Comment: I just re-ran my query in Cosmos DB Studio (in VS Code) just like you're doing. Works fine. Make sure you're using regular double-quotes, and not "smart quotes" (the curved quotes).

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'm using regular double quotes and it does not work in Cosmos DB Studio (desktop client). If I copy the same query into azure portal it works just fine. I do not think the issue has to do with the Cosmos DB Studio desktop client because that same query fails to execute in code when I use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Container.GetItemQueryIterator(sqlString) to execute the query in my .net core 6 project.