# How to filter a column name with spaces or datetime/timestamp values?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Coming in as a complete beginner to this so this is a fairly basic question. How would I be able to filter a column with spaces, and a timestamp value if it is formatted as a string?

```
{
    "TAF_Id": "56874_1_1_000466",
    "Request Form Name": "DS2LIGHTFALL",
    "Created Date": "7/23/2020 12:31:05 PM",
    "Requested By": "User123456",
    "Request Status": "New",
    "ClientId": 123456,
    "Category": "Agent",
    "Last Saved": "7/23/2020 12:31:05 PM",
    "Last Modified By": "User123456",
}
```

I tried the following:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE ["c.Request Status"] = "New"` : Returns 0 rows

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE ["c.Request Status"] = 'New'` : Returns 0 rows

Removing the quotes between from the field name returns the error: `One of the input values is invalid`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name)

Comment: Note that the answer I suggested shows a property name with "`$`" but it still applies, as bracket-notation works the same way for spaces, symbols, reserved words, etc.

Comment: Yes, that thread's solution actually works for me as there are fields with property values in our data. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["Request Status"] = "New"
```