# cosmos db select query array having space and special chars

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to write a query that finds all data that have for e.g. `0.09 pulgadas`

Data in Cosmos is as follows

```
{
    
    "itemId": "62909753",
    "doc": {
        "facets": {
            "tamaño de pantalla": [
                "0.09 pulgadas"
            ]
        }
    },
    "deleted": false,
    "ttl": -1,
    "id": "06e4c982e4f1",
    "_ts": 1678962661
}
```

I am getting syntax errors and I am unable to query due to following issues

- `tamaño de pantalla` has spaces and also has special characters.

Comment: what query you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215137/cosmos-db-sql-query-with-non-alphanumeric-field-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, Is the query that finds all data that have for e.g. `0.09 pulgadas`:

- `SELECT  *  FROM c WHERE c.doc.facets["tamaño de pantalla"] = ["0.09 pulgadas"]`
- **c.doc.facets["tamaño de pantalla"]** This expression retrieves the value of the **"tamaño de pantalla"** field from the **"facets"** property of document in the container.
- I have used [ ] because `0.09 pulgadas` is present in an array so we should retrieve through an array. Hence, I gave **"tamaño de pantalla"** in an array.
- Below is the item in **COSMOS-DB :**

[image]

- The result which I got is in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Please be careful not to answer duplicate questions, and just mark this question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46219609/272109 (pretty much the same question, with same solution). Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)